# How to set display variable for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, cygwin, xserver

So i'm using Cygwin on my local windows machine with Xming Xserver. What I want to do is set the display variable so I can use the full graphical version of my code editor(XEmacs) on the server.

At the moment I can only SSH into my Ubuntu server and use the text version of the program.

Has anyone got any ideas? Is this a permissions error or is there something I'm missing

Comment: What's the actual error you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should tell us what commands you have tried and what was the output you got from them.

Since you can ssh:

`ssh -CX barney@server xemacs`

The -C option is to enable compression. The -X option is to enable X11 forwarding. See the man page of `ssh` for details.

If you're on a local network this should work fine. If you have a high latency you'll get a little frustrated.

This should work from Linux to Linux, I'm not sure about cygwin since I've never used it.

Comment: i voted for this answer based on Cygwin's documentation: Displaying remote X clients with Cygwin/X is nearly identical to displaying remote X clients with any other X Server. You may use the secure ssh method, or the insecure telnet or rsh method (not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin's documentation advises to use -Y instead. Since -Y works, I'd reason that -X works too, but may require special configuration. Pay attention to the notes:

http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using-remote-apps.html

> Note: The ssh server will automatically set the DISPLAY environment
>   variable appropriately, typically to something like localhost:10.0, so
>   clients will connect to a proxy X11 display on the remote host from
>   which the X11 protocol will be forwarded over ssh to your X server.
>
> If your login scripts unconditionally set DISPLAY to something else,
>   this will break X11 forwarding.
>
> Note: By default, the OpenSSH server does not allow forwarded X
>   connections. This must be configured on the remote host by adding
>   X11Forwarding yes to the sshd_config configuration file. The OpenSSH
>   server must be restarted or SIGHUP'ed to re-read the configuration
>   file after it is changed.
>
> Note: The OpenSSH server requires the xauth command to be available to
>   forward X connections. Consequently, it must be installed on the
>   remote host.